# Cannot apply blending to cube located behind half-transparent textured surface

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, textures, blending

Following the tutorial from [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Blending) about rendering half-transparent windows glasses using blending, I tried to apply that principle to my simple scene (where we can navigate the scene using the mouse) containing:

- **Cube:** 6 faces, each having 2 triangles, constructed using two attributes (position and color) defined in its associated vertex shader and passed to its fragment shader.
- **Grass:** 2D Surface (two triangles) to which a png texture was applied using a `sampler2D` uniform (the background of the png image is transparent).
- **Window:** A half-transparent 2D surface based on the same shaders (vertex and fragment) as the grass above. Both textures were downloaded from learnopengl.com

The issue I'm facing is that when it comes to the *Grass*, I can see it through the *Window* but not the *Cube*!

[image: screenshot]

My code is structured as follows (I left the rendering of the window to the very last on purpose):

```cpp
// enable depth test & blending
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);

while (true):
  glClearColor(background.r, background.g, background.b, background.a);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  cube.draw();
  grass.draw();
  window.draw();
```

**Edit:** I'll share below the vertex and fragment shaders used to draw the two textured surfaces (grass and window):

```c
#version 130

in vec2 position;
in vec2 texture_coord;
// opengl tranformation matrices
uniform mat4 model;      // object coord -> world coord
uniform mat4 view;       // world coord  -> camera coord
uniform mat4 projection; // camera coord -> ndc coord
out vec2 texture_coord_vert;

void main() {
  gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
  texture_coord_vert = texture_coord;
}
```

```c
#version 130
in vec2 texture_coord_vert;
uniform sampler2D texture2d;
out vec4 color_out;

void main() {
  vec4 color = texture(texture2d, texture_coord_vert);
  // manage transparency
  if (color.a == 0.0)
    discard;
  color_out = color;
}
```

And the ones used to render the colored cube:

```c
#version 130

in vec3 position;
in vec3 color;
// opengl tranformation matrices
uniform mat4 model;      // object coord -> world coord
uniform mat4 view;       // world coord  -> camera coord
uniform mat4 projection; // camera coord -> ndc coord
out vec3 color_vert;

void main() {
  gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0);
  color_vert = color;
}
```

```c
#version 130

in vec3 color_vert;
out vec4 color_out;

void main() {
  color_out = vec4(color_vert, 1.0);
}
```

**P.S**: My shader programs uses GLSL v1.30, because my internal GPU didn't seem to support later versions.

Regarding the piece of code that does the actual drawing, I basically have one instance of a `Renderer` class for each type of geometry (one shared by both textured surfaces, and one for the cube). This class manages the creation/binding/deletion of VAOs and binding/deletion of VBOs (creation of VBOs made outside the class so I can share vertexes with similar shapes). Its constructor takes as an argument the shader program and the vertex attributes. I'll try to show the relevant piece of code below

```cpp
Renderer::Renderer(Program program, vector attributes) {
  vao.bind();
  vbo.bind();

  define_attributes(attributes);

  vao.unbind();
  vbo.unbind();
}

Renderer::draw(Uniforms uniforms) {
  vao.bind();
  program.use();

  set_uniforms(unfiorms);
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, n_vertexes);

  vao.unbind();
  program.unuse();
}
```

Comment: No, the grass can be seen through the window, it's the cube that's not visible through the window. Please have a look at my edit, I've added my shaders programs and more detail about how rendering is accomplished @Rabbid76

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your blend function function depends on the target's alpha channel (`GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA`):

> ```cpp
> glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);
> ```

```
dest = src * src_alpha + dest * (1-dest_alpha)
```

If the alpha channel of the cube is 0.0, the color of the cube is not mixed with the color of the window.

The  traditional alpha blending function depends only on the source alpha channel:

```cpp
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

```
dest = src * src_alpha + dest * (1-src_alpha)
```

See also [`glBlendFunc`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml) and [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasn't careful enough. It actually explains why I had in the middle of the `grass` surface a region with the same color as the `window`, due to these pixels being fully-opaque in the texture image of the destination.